# Suppose that $\int_a^b f(t)\ \mathrm d\alpha(t)=0$ for all $\alpha(t)$. What can we conclude about f?

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Suppose that $\int_a^b f(t)\ \mathrm d\alpha(t)=0$ for all $\alpha(t)$. What can we conclude about f?

The question has a hint: consider a piecewise constant function $\alpha(t)$. But I still have no idea to do this question.

Comment: That $f=0$,  the proof starts  with "let us suppose the $f$ isn't zero on the interval..."

Comment: Is this meant to apply to a [Riemann-Stieltjes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) or [Lebesgue-Stieltjes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration) Integral?

Comment: @robjohn This is Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Comment: @janmarqz Can you talk more?

Comment: It would be good to include as much context in the question as possible (not only in the comments). Have you read ir7's answer? What is unclear about it?

Comment: @robjohn In the comment, someone said the answer is f = 0. But ir7's answer didn't say f=0.

Comment: Look at the statement of your question, then take a look at the second equation of ir7’s answer. Maybe you’ll see $f(c)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $c\in (a,b)$, take

$$\alpha_c(t)= 1 $$

for all $t\geq c$ and $0$ otherwise. Then note that:

$$ \int_a^b f(t)d\alpha_c(t) = f(c).$$

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2883861/26651) for a formal proof. Basically, we choose $[c-h,c+h], h>0$, to be one of the partition subintervals, giving a contribution to the integral of the form:

$$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(t)(\alpha_c(c+h)-\alpha_c(c-h)). $$

Similar step functions $\alpha$ can be taken to get $f(a)$ ($0$ at $a$ and $1$ otherwise) and $f(b)$ ($1$ at $b$ and $0$ otherwise).

Comment: I am confused. So your answer mean f = f(c) ?

Comment: For every $c$, $f(c)$ can be written as an R-S integral which the problem says that it is $0$. So, $f=0$.